# Value of $\tan A+\tan B+\tan C$ is

Tags: trigonometry

> If $a,b,c$ are the sides of a triangle $ABC$ such that $x^3-24x^2+180x-420=0. $Then $ \tan A+\tan B+\tan C$ is

Try: $a+b+c=24$

$ab+bc+ca=180$ and $abc=420$

And use $a=k\sin A,B=k\sin B, c=k\sin c$ where $k=2R$ circumradius of circle.

After substituting $a,b,c$ in equation. Not getting the term  $\tan A+\tan B+\tan C$

Could some help me thanks

Comment: What is $x$? ${}$

Comment: $=-\frac{96}{793}$

Answer (score 1):

**hint:** $S = \dfrac{abc}{4R}= \dfrac{420}{4R} = \dfrac{105}{R}\implies \dfrac{ab\sin C}{2} = \dfrac{105}{R}\implies \sin C= \dfrac{210}{abR}= \dfrac{210c}{abcR}= \dfrac{c}{2R}$. Use Heron formula to solve for $S = \sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)},p = 12$. Simplify the expression inside square root, and you can solve for $S$ then $R$. To solve for the cosines, solve the system: $a = b\cos C + c\cos B, b = a\cos C + c\cos A, c = a\cos B + b\cos A$ for $\cos A, \cos B, \cos C$ in terms of $a,b,c$. After that, substitute, say $\tan A = \dfrac{\sin A}{\cos A}= \dfrac{ma}{f(a,b,c)}$ with $m$ is a constant and $f(a,b,c)$ is a symmetric polynomial of degree max $3$ of $a,b,c$ and can be found by the above info or at this point, the above info can be useful to get the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If the sides $a,b,c$ of a triangle are the roots of the cubic,
the coefficients can be expressed in terms of
three linear measures of the triangle, 
inradius $r$, circumradius $R$
and semiperimeter $\rho=\tfrac12(a+b+c)$ as follows:

\begin{align}
x^3-2\rho\,x^2+(\rho^2+r^2+4\,r\,R)\,x-4\,r\rho\,R
.
\end{align}

Hence, for the given equation
\begin{align}
x^3-24\,x^2+180\,x-420
&=0
\end{align}

we have

\begin{align}
\rho&=12
,\\
4\,r\,R&=35
,\\
r&=\sqrt{180-12^2-35}=1
,\\
R&=\tfrac{35}4
.
\end{align}

The sum of the tangents 
can be also expressed in similar way as

\begin{align}
\tan\alpha+\tan\beta+\tan\gamma
&=\frac{2\,r\,\rho}{\rho^2-(r+2\,R)^2}
\end{align}

With known values of $r,R$ and $\rho$
it is trivial to find that
\begin{align}
\tan\alpha+\tan\beta+\tan\gamma&=-\frac{96}{793}
.
\end{align}