# Radius of a circle inscribed in a right triangle is given, the hypotenuse is given, find the legs?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, triangles

The radius of the circle inscribed in the right triangle is 4, the hypotenuse is 20cm. How do I find the legs? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**:$$r = \cfrac{b+p - h}2$$,

$$b^2 + p^2 = h^2$$
Now you can solve to get answer

Comment: https://www.nextgurukul.in/nganswers/ask-question/answer/Prove-that-the-radius-r-of-the-circle-which-touches-the-sides-of-the-triangle-is-given-by-rabc2/Circles/93658.htm

Comment: Its easy to prove, alternatively you can use $r = \cfrac{b*p}{b+p+h}$

Answer (score 1):

For the right triangle $ABC$
with 
the hypotenuse $|AB|=c=20$ and
the radius of inscribed circle $r=4$,
the radius of circumscribed circle is known to be
found as
\begin{align}
R&=\tfrac{c}2=10
, 
\end{align}

and the semiperimeter 
\begin{align} 
\rho&=\tfrac12(a+b+c)
=r+c
,
\end{align}

Considering the side lengths of the triangle
as [the roots of a general cubic polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2639525/122782)
in terms of semiperimeter $\rho$,
inradius $r$ and circumradius $R$,

\begin{align}
x^3-2\rho\,x^2+(\rho^2+r^2+4\,r\,R)\,x-4\,r\rho\,R
,
\end{align}

we can first simplify this cubic using the information given to

\begin{align}
x^3-2(r+c) x^2+((r+c)^2+r^2+2r c) x-2(r+c)r c
&=
(x-c)(x^2-(2r+c)x+2(r+c)r)
\\
\text{and find the legs as }\quad
a,b&=r+\tfrac{c}2\pm\tfrac12\sqrt{c^2-4r(r+c)}
=16,12
.
\end{align}

[image]